# react unmouting when navigate away

Tags: url-routing, reactjs, html5-history

i have this react component which works so will when i render it

```
var Postlist = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    socket.on("new",this.Updatepost);
    return {posts: [], hasMore: true, onView: 5};
},
componentWillMount: function () {
    this.state.posts.push(this.props.newposts);
    this.setState({posts: this.props.newposts});
},
$.ajax({
    url: 'load_posts.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var x = data;
        React.render(<Postlist newposts={x} />,document.getElementById("main"));
    }.bind(this),
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
});
```

but iam using history api to navigate between pages

so how can i unmount and remount react component when navigating and how to unmounting it outside react code

Comment: Have you looked into using any of the React-friendly routing components?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can do that , react handles the lifecycle of a component by itself , so i think the way to work around this should be something like actually save the previous state within the browser history .. so when you go back and forth you can tell react that should update by pushing a "new" state

Comment: okay how to do that i just want react to work fine with history

Comment: listening to the event window.onpopstate  , when that events is triggered it means that you went back or foward in the history ..  so you can "Re Render" your component again with React.render()